# Statsmodels: How does statsmodels' VAR(p ) / VAR(p) in general works?

Tags: vector-autoregression, statsmodels

I'm trying to use statsmodels' VAR(p) to forecast some data points in the future.
Below is a snapshot of what my data looks like:

[image]

What I understand about VAR(p) equation in general is that when p = 3, VAR(p) will use 3 lags time to predict the future. What I'm not sure is whether it uses 3 lags time consecutively or 3 lags time at a specific time.

**For example (using my data):**

A. p = 3, means 2016-08-15 00:20:00, 2016-08-15 00:15:00, 2016-08-15 00:10:00

OR

B. p = 3, means 2016-08-15 00:20:00, 2016-08-14 00:20:00, 2016-08-13 00:20:00
(same hour at different days)

Then, when it forecast the future, does it forecast the future consecutively or at same hour different days?

**For example** (to predict 3 data points), does VAR(p) outputs forecasted points on the following dates?

A. 2016-08-15 00:25:00, 2016-08-15 00:30:00, 2016-08-15 00:35:00

OR

B. 2016-08-16 00:20:00, 2016-08-17 00:20:00, 2016-08-18 00:20:00

Maybe I'm just way off...I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking for clarification.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

In general (not specifically about statsmodels), a VAR(p) model is built according to your option "A".

You are correct in that the value of a series the previous day at the same time may be useful in forecasting. Generally this is referred to as "seasonality" (because if you have monthly data, the *season* within the year may have some predictive power...this is the same, but about the time within the day).

I don't know if your specific package will do it, but generically you can build a seasonal version of a VAR(p) model by adding a lag at the seasonal period (12 x 24 = 288 five minute intervals). For example, in your case, you could build something like:

$Y_t = A_1 Y_{t-1} + A_{288} Y_{t-288} + e_t$

This model would depend both on the value 5 minutes ago and on the value at this hour yesterday.